# Sugar orm findAll return Empty List next to add MultiDex and upgrade to sugar 1.4 to 1.5

Tags: android, sugarorm

I have this application runnning with the sugar version 1.4 without Multidex and it's works.

But when I upgraded the sugar orm to 1.5 and I added MultiDex the functions indall or listAll of the sugar orm returns an empty list or a objects list with the attributes=null.

Then I added a summary of Application class, AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle related to add MultiDex and upgrade sugar 1.4 to 1.5 and next I added an example model (EventType) and example of the execution and it's result.

**Context**

MyApplication.class

```
public class MyApplication extends SugarApp{

@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication">
<application/>
```

build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}


dependencies {

compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**Problem**

All of this code was tested in a new installation of the app, adding new registers, that I verified that was saved in the database.

The model of EventType:

```
    public class EventType  extends SugarRecord implements Type{

        @SerializedName("id")
        private Long identifier;
        @SerializedName("name")
        private String name;
        @SerializedName("image")
        private String image;

        private boolean selected= false;

        public EventType() {
        }
}
```

When I executed:

```
 EventType.listAll(EventType.class)
```

Returns and empty list with this error:

```
SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM EVENT_TYPE
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at com.blabla.Models.Event.EventType.hashCode(EventType.java:87)
W/System.err:     at sun.misc.Hashing.singleWordWangJenkinsHash(Hashing.java:48)
```

And when I executed:

```
Lists.newArrayList(EventType.findAll(EventType.class))
```

Returns and array with the attr null but with the size of the registers that I have in the db:

```
DAODBEventType: SAVE:[Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}, Type{name='null'}]
```

Someone has been found with a similar problem, any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Currently, It looks like a zebra... Wanna get hunted by down-votes and end-up in triage review? (a.k.a. purgatory for dubious questions)! Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: @ZF007 I have updated, I hope it's clearer now, thanks for the comment

Comment: Much better, well done (+1 upvote for the effort) !! Lets hope the "expert" fish will byte... ;-)